# How to add a focus ring to TextEditor in SwiftUI for MacOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

In contrast to TextField which has an animated blue focus ring, the TextEditor control doesn't have it. How can this be added? It should look and behave (i.e. animations) exactly like the one from TextField, so just adding a border isn't enough.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By using something like [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect), you could do:

```
struct TextEditorWithFocusRing: View {

    @Binding var text: String

    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $text)
            .introspectTextView { textView in
                textView.enclosingScrollView?.focusRingType = .exterior
            }
        }
    }

}
```